# shuffle elements of a matrix's column to correlate to another column of the matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, shuffle

I have a matrix of human height in R like:

```
#the first 4 rows of 400 total
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  178  162
[2,]  186  157
[3,]  179  159
[4,]  180  157
```

I need to shuffle elements of second column i.e `x[,2]` so that `cor(x[,1],x[,2])`≈0.6 or anything more than 0.5, and I want to keep `x[,1]` untouched. (for now it has a very weak correlation of <0.1)
anybody know how to do this? thanks in advance.

Comment: First determine what the untouched correlation is and then decide whether you want increase or decrease the starting value. The use `sample` on an appropriately sized subset.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Comment: Try something like:  mat[ 2:nrow(mat), 2 ] <- mat[ 2:nrow(mat),2] [order(mat[ 2:nrow(mat) ,1 )]

Comment: thanks but still I have no Idea ...

Comment: Hi, I am also very interested in this solution. At moment, I didn't find a way to keep the korrelation. If you look at the formel of correlation, it is nearly impossible. You need to garantie: E(xy) = E(xy'), x is your first column, y is you second column, and y' is the new array after shuffling.